# Excluding the derived classes in the Count funtion in entity framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following statement.

```
 List<ApplicationUserDto> peers = _context.ApplicationUsers
        .Select(m => new ApplicationUserDto
          {
              Id = m.Id,
              MyCount = m.GroupMemberships
                         .Count(pg => pg.StudentGroup.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId)
          }).ToList();
```

I have another class, called `PeerStudentGroup` derived from `StudentGroup`. In the `Count()` function, I do not want them to be included. I mean I want to count only if it is `StudentGroup` type (not another class derived from it). I wonder how I can achieve this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use the [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) keyword which compares instance types. You should add `!(pg.StudentGroup is PeerStudentGroup)` to your condition.

Your code should look like this:

```
 List<ApplicationUserDto> peers = _context.ApplicationUsers
        .Select(m => new ApplicationUserDto
          {
              Id = m.Id,
              MyCount = m.GroupMemberships
                         .Count(pg => pg.StudentGroup.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId && !(pg.StudentGroup is PeerStudentGroup))
          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help to start with:

Apply a .Where (filtering) statement before the projection (Select) like

`MyCount = m.GroupMemberships
   .Where(gm => !(gm is PeerStudentGroup)) 
   [alternatively] typeof(gm) != typeof(PeerStudentGroup)
   .Count(pg => pg.StudentGroup.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId)`